# C++ pow() - Mismatch type for float

Tags: c++

I have made a simple code in C++

```
#include<math.h>

void main()
{
float a,x;

    cout<<"Enter value of a"<<endl;
    cin>>a;

    x = pow(a,0.5);
    cout<<x;
}
```

But it's giving me error:

[image: Error for Pow() use with float in C++]

When I press F12 and go to definition of `pow()`, these 6 overloads are found:

[image: math.h pow() overloads]

As we can see, it clearly has one overload for (`double`, `double`) and one for (`float`, `float`), so why does it give error when I declare `a` as `float` and works perfectly when I change its data-type to `double`?

Comment: The problem is that you pass a `float` as the first argument and a `double` as second argument, and no overload matches that exactly so one of the arguments have to be converted, but the compiler can't decide which conversion to make for you.

Comment: 0.5 is probably ambiguous. Modify it to 0.5f so it will be interpreted as a float literal.

Comment: @LeandroVaz : 0.5 is not ambiguous - it's a literal of type `double`.

Comment: @Bob Jarvis: Yes I know, that's why I told him to change to 0.5f, so it would match the (float, float) overload. I didn't actually mean to say that it was ambiguous.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Unless I'm mistaken (on the overloads of `pow`), I'm surprised the standard doesn't just state to upcast the float to a double. Why would one want to downcast a double to a float without a cast?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is that the literal `0.5` is a `double`, so you are calling `pow` with a set of arguments that do not unambiguously match an overload, and for which type conversions cannot be applied to unambiguously match an existing overload. You should use the float literal `0.5f` instead.

```
x = pow(a, 0.5f);
```

Also note that you need to `#include <iostream>` for `cout`, `cin` and `endl`, and you have to either refer to them by their full names (`std::cout`, `std::cin`, `std::endl`), or use using declarations

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
```

Finally, `void main()` is not one of the valid signatures for the `main` function. It must return int, so

```
int main()
```

or

```
auto main()->int
```

Comment: **auto main()->int** wow, never though about declaring entry point like so. it makes code look more like C++

Comment: I have done all #include<iostream> and using namespace std thing obviously

Comment: Since `int main()` is the most familiar entry point in C++, I don't recommend using this form `auto main()->int`, it's obfuscated.

Comment: @deepmax It won't be obfuscated when people get used to it. But I wouldn't use it either, at least not at this point in time. But it is a valid form of the parameterless signature.

Comment: @TalhaIrfan Do not use `using namespace std;`! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 3):

You're calling it with a `float` and a `double`. There isn't an overload for that combination, and several that are close enough to be ambiguous.

`0.5f` would have type `float`, if you want to use the overload with two `float` parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly call an overloaded function of `pow()`

```
x = pow(a, 0.5f);
```

or

```
double y = pow(static_cast<double>(a), 0.5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your call doesn't *exactly* match any of the various definitions of  `pow`, so the compiler is trying to see if it can automatically cast some of your arguments so it will exactly match, but here there are 6 possible definitions of `pow` that could match. You need to tell the compiler exactly which one you want.

What you tried to call is `pow(float, double)`, because 0.5 is a double literal (**not** a float!).

If you do for example `pow(a, 0.5f)` then both arguments are float and it will compile. Of course you could also pick any of the other 5 overloads.